# How to deal with punctuation marks and capitalization on a reversed String?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm getting users input from an EditText, reverse it then output on a TextView. Everything works fine except that the strings output as entered, example `StackOverflow is a community of awesome programmers!` becomes `!programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow`.

Now I would like:

- Capitalize the first letter when the string get inverted : `Programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow`
- Have that exclamation mark, or any other punctuation marks, be placed at the end instead of the beginning. Our example should be: `programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow !`

I use the code below to reverse the string:

```
        String[] nowTyping = input.getText().toString().split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> wordArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : nowTyping) {
            wordArray.add(0, word);
        }
        String invertedSentence = TextUtils.join(" ", wordArray);
        output.setText(invertedSentence);
```

I already tried `android:inputType="textCapWords"` to capitalize the first letter, but doesn't seem to work.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
String[] nowTyping = "It is broken!".split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> wordArray = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> symbolsArray = new ArrayList<>();
            int cnt=0;
            for (int j=nowTyping.length-1 ;j >=0;j--) {
                String word = nowTyping[j];
                if (word.length()>0) {
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                    char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
                    if (cnt == 0) {
                        boolean isFirstCharFounded = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                            if (!isFirstCharFounded&&Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(i))) {
                                firstChar = word.charAt(i);
                                isFirstCharFounded = true;
                            } else if (!(Character.isDigit(word.charAt(i))||Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(i)))) {
                                symbolsArray.add(word.charAt(i) + "");
                                word = word.replace(word.charAt(i)+"","");
                            }
                        }

                        firstChar = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    if (word.length()>=2) {
                        word = firstChar + word.substring(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        word = firstChar + "";
                    }

                    wordArray.add( word);
                }
            }
            String invertedSentence = TextUtils.join(" ", wordArray);
            invertedSentence += TextUtils.join("",symbolsArray);
```

Comment: This capitalizes the first letter of the entered string and moves the punctuation at the end of the word in which it is used. example: `It didn't work!`=> `work! didn't It` (here it has a capital i)

Comment: Yes so what you want to do ?

Comment: I want something like : `It didn't work!` => `Work didn't it!`.

Comment: so you want '!' at end of string ?

Comment: The end of the sentence, here the end of the array.  I just realized how complex this question can be :D

Comment: Okay i'll try for you :)

Comment: Ah, and with your code, the app crashes with `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` when you delete the content of the input. It especially crashes when trying to delete the last element (from right to left)

Comment: required to set conditions for substring function

Comment: How to prevent that from happening? remember I'm using TextWatcher `onTextChanged()`, so it is updating the textView. This is were the error points: `char firstChar=word.charAt(0);`

Comment: Tried. Now something like `It is broken!` becomes `broken! is Itt`spot double "t" here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178305/discussion-between-tejas-trivedi-and-esqmo).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a StringBuilder:

```
    String invertedSentence = "!programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(invertedSentence);

    if (!Character.isLetter(stringBuilder.charAt(0))) {
        char mark = stringBuilder.charAt(0);
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(mark);
    }

    if (!Character.isUpperCase(stringBuilder.charAt(0))) {
        char mark = stringBuilder.charAt(0);
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.insert(0, Character.toUpperCase(mark));
    }

    invertedSentence = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this seems not to work, both moving the marks and capitalizing. Android doesn't seem to have that function, any equivalence?

Comment: Well, this moves the punctuation at the end of the string only. If we have a sentence, the punctuation will move at the end of the word. Exemple: `Bla ble bli !` => `bli! ble Bla`. And the uppercase doesn't work